# ¿Cómo leo objetos y los guardo en un array en java?

Tags: java, array, poo, objeto

Quiero leer todos los objetos de un fichero y guardarlos en un array pero siempre me lee el mismo objeto por lo que nunca me sale del while. Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

```
        String fileJ = "Fichero.txt";
        boolean obj = true;
        try {
            while (obj) {
                ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileJ));
                Coche coche = (Coche) input.readObject();
                if (coche != null)
                    this.coches.add(coche);
                else
                    obj = false;
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            File f = new File("fichero.txt");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el contenido de la clase Coche y el contenido del archivo "Fichero.txt"?. Sospecho que la variable coche es siempre null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema en este código es que se está abriendo el archivo en cada iteración del bucle while. Como resultado, cada vez que se lee un objeto del archivo, se comienza a leer el archivo desde el principio.

Codigo:

```
String fileJ = "Fichero.txt";
try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileJ))) {
    boolean obj = true;
    while (obj) {
        Coche coche = (Coche) input.readObject();
        if (coche != null) {
            this.coches.add(coche);
        } else {
            obj = false;
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    File f = new File("fichero.txt");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```